# Iterating over sets in c++

Tags: c++, vector, set

Either I'm blind or `std::set` behaves a lot differently than `std::vector` when it comes to overloading the output operator. Consider the code below.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<int>& myset) {
    for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = myset.begin(); it < myset.end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
        return os;
    }
}

int main () {}
```

If one replaces `std::set` by `std::vector` in two places and `<set>` by `<vector>` in the includes, then the code works as expected. Where is the difference? My compiler (g++) gives weird error messages such as the following.

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:297:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

So even though I'm explicitly telling that I'm using `std::set<int>` it somehow fails and this behavior happens only for `std::set`.

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: `it < myset.end()` -- shouldn't that be `it != myset.end()` ?

Comment: Also, you are missing a closing brace for the `for` loop.

Comment: You have mismatched `{}`. And `set` iterator is not random-access so doesn't have `operator<`.

Comment: Please post **real code**. Copy and paste it. First reduce it to a minimal (but complete) example.

Comment: Thank you all. I corrected the code. I copied the code, but it was not correctly formatted and in the process of making it so I deleted a }. Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work in both cases you loop should be:

```
for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
```

`it < myset.end()` works only for random access iterator where `std::set::iterator` is bidirectional.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) you can read what bidirectional iterator provides vs [random access one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition is wrong `it < myset.end();`. A `std::set::iterator` can't be compared with the `<` operator since it's not a random access iterator. The error messages in [this sample](http://ideone.com/Y6CEvm) are clearer about that.

To fix, compare using the `!=` operator:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<int>& myset) {
    for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = myset.begin(); it !=  myset.end(); ++it) {
                                                           // ^^
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;
}

int main () {}
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/5qmR8A)</kbd>

---

BTW you had a missing `}` for the for loop body in your sample.

Answer (score 1):

Your code built fine after changing the loop to

```
for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
```

Note that, in general, you cannot assume that you can less-than compare iterators.

Some containers' iterators might support this (and this might possibly also depend on the implementation), but you should really not rely on this.

Comment: The iterators don't need to be pointers in order to be comparable with `operator<`. They just need to be random access iterators, which includes `vector`, `deque`, `basic_string`, and `array` from the standard library.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer. Out of curiosity, s there any algorithm or container that actually uses this? I can't recall any. Again, many thanks.

Comment: It follows from the standard library's requirements for what it takes to qualify as a random access iterator. It requires all 6 comparison operators, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`, whether any specific algorithms require those operations or not.